# Wordpress Posts in each category in different DIVs

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm having a wordpress problem. I'm trying to get three divs that toggle visibility when a user clicks a link. My problem is that all the results from each WP_Query are under the `HomeDisplaySel` div. I've counted where each div begins and end, and even added extra end divs, but nothing works. I cant separate each post category into different divs. Thanks for the help.

```
<div id="HomeDisplaySel">
    <?php $AllPostsArgs = array ('posts_per_page' => 6, 'category' => 'posts'); ?>
    <?php $AllPosts = new WP_Query($AllPostsArgs); ?>
    <?php while($AllPosts->have_posts()) : $AllPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
    <div id="Author">
    <?php $authID = get_the_author_meta('ID'); ?>
    <?php echo get_avatar($authID); ?>
    <h5><?php the_author();?></h5><br />
    <h5><?php the_author_meta('user_description'); ?></h5>
    </div>
    <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
    <br />
    <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
    <hr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<div id="WKTSel">
    <?php $AllPostsArgs = array ('posts_per_page' => 6, 'category' => 'workouts'); ?>
    <?php $WKTS = new WP_Query("posts_per_page=6&category=workouts"); ?>
    <?php while($WKTS->have_posts()) : $$WKTS->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
    <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
    <br />
    <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
    <hr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<div id="THPYSel">
    <?php $AllPostsArgs = array ('posts_per_page' => 6, 'category' => 'therapy'); ?>
    <?php $WKTS = new WP_Query("posts_per_page=6&category=workouts"); ?>
    <?php while($WKTS->have_posts()) : $$WKTS->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
    <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
    <br />
    <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
    <hr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

EDIT

When I go to view the source in chrome, heres what I see.

```
<!-- Home Page -->

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title> | The MindStream Academy Blog</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monda' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/wp-content/themes/mindstream/style.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="changehome.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<img src="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/logo.png" alt="MindStream_Academy_Logo" id="logo" />
</div><div id="sidebar">
<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/?page_id=8">Home</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/?page_id=9">About</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/?page_id=11">Students</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-14"><a href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/?page_id=14">Archives</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/?page_id=13">Fan Mail</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-16"><a href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/?page_id=16">Contact</a></li>
</div><div id="main">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="changehome.js"></script>
<div class="col">
<div class="ChangeHome">
<h2><a href='#' id='LoadRP'>Recent<br />Posts</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="ChangeHome">
<h2><a href='#' id='LoadWOTW'>Workout of<br />the Week</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="ChangeHome">
<h2><a href='#' id='LoadWT'>Weekly Therapy</a></h2>
</div>
</div>

<div id="HomeDisplaySel">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/?p=43"><h1>Workout #1</h1></a>
    <div id="Author">
        <img width="96" height="96" src="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Ian-clarke-headshot-1-150x150.png" class="avatar avatar-96 photo wp-post-image" alt="" />  <h5>Hunter Willis</h5><br />
    <h5>2012 Fall &amp; Spring</h5>
    </div>
    <h4>Posted on February 16th, 2013</h4>
    <br />
    <p><p>Hey all. How is everyone? Pumped? I know I am! Here is a workout for your arms and core to [...]</p>
</p>
    <hr>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/?p=36"><h1>Test 3</h1></a>
    <div id="Author">
        <img width="96" height="96" src="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Ian-clarke-headshot-1-150x150.png" class="avatar avatar-96 photo wp-post-image" alt="" />  <h5>Hunter Willis</h5><br />
    <h5>2012 Fall &amp; Spring</h5>
    </div>
    <h4>Posted on February 6th, 2013</h4>
    <br />
    <p><p>Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test [...]</p>
</p>
    <hr>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/?p=33"><h1>Test 2</h1></a>
    <div id="Author">
        <img width="96" height="96" src="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Ian-clarke-headshot-1-150x150.png" class="avatar avatar-96 photo wp-post-image" alt="" />  <h5>Hunter Willis</h5><br />
    <h5>2012 Fall &amp; Spring</h5>
    </div>
    <h4>Posted on February 6th, 2013</h4>
    <br />
    <p><p>Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test [...]</p>
</p>
    <hr>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/?p=26"><h1>Test</h1></a>
    <div id="Author">
        <img width="96" height="96" src="http://localhost:8888/MindstreamBlog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Ian-clarke-headshot-1-150x150.png" class="avatar avatar-96 photo wp-post-image" alt="" />  <h5>Hunter Willis</h5><br />
    <h5>2012 Fall &amp; Spring</h5>
    </div>
    <h4>Posted on January 25th, 2013</h4>
    <br />
    <p><p>Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test testeroo! Test test [...]</p>
</p>
    <hr>
    </div>

<div id="WKTSel">
```

Comment: Nothing is jumping out of the code at me. Got a demo? Off topic: If you're using <br />, you should probably also be using <hr />.

Comment: I'm running it off my local machine with MAMP. I'll post what chrome's source is.

Comment: I see extra opening <p> tags and the author div is in there twice. It's hard to see what's happening since your demo text isn't indicative of which section it's from.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the nested paragraphs and make the rules self-closing:

```
<?php the_excerpt(__('(more...)')); ?>
<hr />
```